# What is "Kies via Wi-Fi" in S3?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung-kies

I see that "Kies via Wi-Fi" sends only 2.3 kb and receives only 876 bytes the last four hours in my phone, but it uses 26 mins of my phone CPU time and 20% of my phone battery. Is it something that I can stop it? If yes, how to stop it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kies via WiFi (a stock ROM app) connects your phone to the Kies software on your computer via WiFi.

I am on CM10.1, which doesn't have Kies via WiFi. BUT, there is probably a setting in the Kies via WiFi app that lets you disable the auto-connect function.

Comment: Alternatively, when running Android 4.0+, it might be an option to simply freeze (disable) that app/service? I don't have a Samsung phone, so I cannot tell for sure -- but that would be what I'd look for if not using such an app.

Answer (score 0):

It is an app that is used to update your smartphone or tablet. The only way to kill it is to root your phone and uninstall it. It is a system app and cannot be killed.

Answer (score 0):

open kies via wifi, go to the settings, and turn off Autoconnect.

`Settings -> More Settings -> Kies via Wi-Fi -> Settings -> Auto connect off`